# Seesaw: Multiline text field not shrinking with frame

Tags: swing, clojure, seesaw

I mount the following seesaw code `(:require [seesaw.core :as ss])` into any frame:

```
(ss/scrollable
 (ss/grid-panel         
  :items [(ss/scrollable
           (ss/text
            :rows 8
            :multi-line? true
            :wrap-lines? false
            :text "this is good"))

          (ss/scrollable
           (ss/text
            :rows 8
            :multi-line? true
            :wrap-lines? true
            :text "this is bad"))]))
```

Both fields should scale with the frame. The second field, however, will only expand but not contract horizontally, so I keep getting horizontal scrollbars (which I don't like, see screenshot). **The only difference is `:wrap-lines?` being set to `true` in the problematic case.**

The problems also arises with other containers (mig-panel, vertical-panel…) the only difference being that sometimes the field expands indefinitely in horizontal direction.

Any explanations for that or ideas how to circumvent it?

Many thanks!

Oliver

Seesaw version: 1.5.0; 
Clojure version: 1.10.0

[image]

Comment: I suggest getting this to work in pure Java before translating it into Seesaw / Clojure. There will be a lot more people willing / able to help. At a random guess, ypu might try specifying a number of columns as well.